Tkinter, macbook air M1, click not working well
I have been experiencing a problem for the past few weeks. Indeed, I'm using Python 3.8.13 and Tkinter 8.6.12 on my MacBook Air M1 with macOS Sonoma 14.5 (23F79). When I need to click a button using tk.Button(), or when I want to enter some text using tk.Entry(), I have to click multiple times before the event registers.
Do you know what I can do to fix this problem?
Thank you !
import tkinter as tk

def popup():
  new_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
  new_window.title("Title")
  label = tk.Label(new_window, text="Test", font=("Arial", 20))
  label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test button")

bouton = tk.Button(root, text="Click !", command=popup)
bouton.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()


EDIT: The problem was solved using:
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```


Without seeing a [mre] it's hard to say if this is a software problem or a hardware problem.

Post the code in the question instead of comment.

I modified the question by adding the code. Thanks

Try reinstalling Python from python.org.

https://devcodef1.com/news/1276910/tkinter-click-button-issue-on-macbook-air-m1

@toyotaSupra good find!

The problem is solved. I did edit the question.
